# Does removing objects of an array equal to another array remove them from both arrays?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

Ok, say I do this.

```
NSMutableArray *array1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"poop", @"on", @"your", @"face", nil];

NSMutableArray *array2=array1;


[array2 removeAllObjects];
```

now does array1 have objects in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];
```

Creates a mutable array object in memory with strings @"one and @"two" ..and make an array object pointer `array1` point to that object in memory.

[image]

```
NSMutableArray *array2 = array1;
```

Create another pointer `array2` of type NSMutableArray, and make it point to the same object in memory that array1 is pointing to.

[image]

```
[array2 removeAllObjects];
```

Remove all strings from the mutable Array object that is pointed to by array2

[image]

Now since array1 and array2 points to the same object in memory, both array1 and array2 will now point to a mutable array object in memory that has no objects in it.

Comment: Thanks. You can add images to your answers by clicking on the image icon.. its located between the *code sample* and *number list* icons that are on the menu bar just above the text-box you type the answer in.

Answer (score 2):

First, have you tried it out to see what happens? :) That should answer your question right away. As far as *why* it happens, it's because there is only one array in this instance. `array2` is simply a pointer to `array1` (i.e., they both point to the same `NSMutableArray` instance). So yes, if you refer to the array using `array1`, you will see that it is empty.

Now if you had the following:

```
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
[array2 removeAllObjects];
```

`array1` will still have its elements because `array2` is an entirely new `NSMutableArray` instance.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to know if an object is different. you can do == comparison. or check the %p pointer value.

```
if (array1 == array2) { NSLog(@"These variables point to the same array"); }

NSLog(@"Address of Array1 is (%p) Address of Array2 is (%p)",array1, array2);
```

This will give you some idea when id objects are different or are the exact same object.

if the pointers are the same value. they are the same object. and `(obj1 == obj2)` will result in `YES` when the objects pointers are the same value.